# Redirect or Prevent Viewing of Custom Taxonomy's Archives?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives, archive-template

I've contacted the theme developer but never got a response back... I'm also curious to see if anyone else has done this with any theme.

To give you a live example:

1. http://demo.powerthemes.club/themes/couponxl/search-page/location/alabama/ , provides viewers deals/offers in the location taxonomy Alabama.
2. However, web crawlers, etc, can view - http://demo.powerthemes.club/themes/couponxl/location/alabama/ , which looks like a Blog post.

Is there a way to make it so that people viewing a custom taxonomy archive get redirected to the homepage? or, even better, to the actual search page? Do I perhaps have to create a custom archive-template?

thanks!

Comment: You don't want anyone to see the archive pages?

Comment: No, because the archive displays duplicated deals/offers, uses the blog template, and displays expired deals/offers; which is something I didn't want. I posted the solution below :)

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my child-theme's functions.php file and it works 100%

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_archive' );
function redirect_archive() {
    if ( is_tax('location') ) {
        $termurl = get_query_var( 'term' );
        wp_redirect( home_url('/search/location/'.$termurl), 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
```